# Hibernate, how to avoid duplicates?

Tags: hibernate, duplicates

my table has 3 columns: ID, City, District.

My web service give in input a list of couples (City, District). I need to avoid couples (City, District) duplicates.

How can I achieve this result?
I can't use session.saveOrUpdate() because due to a different ID, all the records seems always different.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: The first thing to do would be to add a constraint to your table: `CONSTRAINT city_district_unique UNIQUE (city, district)`. The exact syntax will vary depending on the database you're using.

Comment: Maybe you could use a composite key consisting of city and district properties.

Answer (score 4):

The comment suggests what you should do

```
CONSTRAINT city_district_unique UNIQUE (city, district)
```

create a UNIQUE constraint for the fields. This can also be done with JPA annotations when you want to create the table with Hibernate

```
@Table(name = "yourtable", uuniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "subject"), ... })
```

When inserting, you should catch the Exception from the violation of the above constraint and handle it properly, like re-running the insert with changed parameters or ignore it at all. Even better, check your data befor it gets to Hibernate to avoid the invalid inserts beforehand.

Comment: 1) is it possible to do it AFTER table creation?
2) I don't find MYSql documentation for your syntax